# MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ETIMEDOUT

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I recently ran into this problem. When I try to run my Node.js app, I get this error `MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ETIMEDOUT`. It also said `type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary'`. For the past few months it was working perfectly and I had never got this error. I am using MongoDB Atlas for the database and Mongoose for its driver. I am using the latest version of Mongoose.

Here is my `app.ts`:

```js
const CONNECTION_URL = "mongodb+srv://name:<password>@cluster0.vyegx.mongodb.net/MyApp?retryWrites=true&w=majority"

mongoose.connect(CONNECTION_URL).then(_INIT_)

async function _INIT_(){
    const server = app.listen(PORT, ()=>{
        console.log("listening on port "+PORT+"...")
    });
    const io = new Server(server);
}
```

I have tried to whitelist my ip, but it's not working.

**UPDATE** It works perfectly with no errors in Heroku but when I try to run it from my computer it gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

need to set  `useUnifiedTopology: false`

Comment: I am using typescript and I cannot find that option